# Handling errors for different response status in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, http, exception

I am developing a fullstack app with Spring Boot and React and there are different status codes and bodies for the following situations:

***when credentials are wrong:*** 500

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "message": "Bad credentials"
}
```

***when there is validation errors:*** 422

```
{
    "status": 422,
    "message": "Validation error. Check 'errors' field for details",
    "errors": [
        {
            "field": "password",
            "message": "size must be between 6 and 100"
        }
    ]
}
```

I display error messages. However, based on the situations, I have to check the response error fields or status codes and I thought to check using `?` as shown below:

```
.catch((error) => {
  error.response.data.errors?.map(e => enqueueSnackbar(e.message, "error"))
  enqueueSnackbar(error.response.data.message?, "error");
});
```

But I am not sure if there is a more elegant way to handle these 2 different error types. Any idea?

**Update:** I could also implement exception logic in the service methods, but I cannot use the `enqueueSnackbar` method in the service. Because I export service methods as shown below. Any idea how can I use my alert method in this?

***Login.tsx:***

```
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";
// ...
const Login = () => {

  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
           // ...
      .catch((error) => {
        enqueueSnackbar(error.response.data.message, { variant: "error" });
      });
  };
    // ...
};

export default Login;
```

But when I try to use `enqueueSnackbar` method in the service, I get "React Hook "useSnackbar" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function." error.

***service.js:***

```
import axios from "./axios";
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";

// !!! here I get error
const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

// if the error is fixed, I could use `enqueueSnackbar` in this method 
export const postWithoutAuth = (url, body) => {
  const request = axios.post(url, body);
  return request.then((response) => response.data);
};

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an elegant way to handle errors in a `catch` statement by using `instanceof` or some libraries methods:

```js
import { ValidationError } from "yup";
import axios from 'axios';

try {
  // ..
} catch (error) {

  // handling yup validation error
  if (error instanceof ValidationError) {
    console.error(error.errors.join(", "))
    return
  }

  // handling axios request error
  if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
    console.error(error.response?.data)
    return
  }

  // add any other lib errors instances

  if (error instanceof Error) {
    console.error(error.message)
    return
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds good, but I export each method in the service class and cannot use my alert method in these methods (please see my update). So, how can I use my alert method in this service method?

Comment: No, it is not a different question. I just need to use `enqueueSnackbar(error.response.data.message?, "error");` in the service, but I cannot add it to the service via `const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();`. So, how can I use it in the service?

Comment: Ok, for you I created a separate question. Could you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75719668/react-hook-usex-cannot-be-called-at-the-top-level-error

Comment: Looks like your first question, (1) how to handle error conditionally is answered. Regarding your second answer (2) how to use hook outside a component, the answer is: you cannot. Please, read the react documentation. A hint is to create a custom hook or using context!

Comment: ` if (error instanceof ValidationError) {` is not valid for JavaScript, why don't you suggest something without testing?