# React Hook "useX" cannot be called at the top level error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to move the following exception logic in the component to my service class:

***Login.tsx:***

```
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";
// ...
const Login = () => {

  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
           // ...
      .catch((error) => {
        enqueueSnackbar(error.response.data.message, { variant: "error" });
      });
  };
    // ...
};

export default Login;
```

But when I try to use enqueueSnackbar method in the service, I get "React Hook "useSnackbar" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function." error.

***service.js:***

```
import axios from "./axios";
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";

// !!! here I get error
const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

// if the error is fixed, I could use `enqueueSnackbar` in this method 
export const postWithoutAuth = (url, body) => {
  const request = axios.post(url, body);
  return request.then((response) => response.data);
};

// ...
```

So, how can I use `enqueueSnackbar` in my service methods e.g. `postWithoutAuth` ?

Comment: You can't use hook outside your functional component. The only way is.. make a custom hook and move your service code in the hook to use useSnackbaar.

Comment: Please refer: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-react-hooks/

Comment: I already read it before asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

React hooks can only be called from React function components or custom React hooks. If you want to use the `useSnackbar` in the "service" code outside a React component then you'll need to convert the "service" code into a custom React hook.

Example:

```js
import axios from "./axios";
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";

// Create a custom hook
export const usePostWithoutAuth = () => {
  // call useSnackbar hook
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  // create POSTing function with special error handling
  const postWithoutAuth = async (url, body) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(url, body);
      return response.data;
    } catch(error) {
      // dispatch snackbar/toast with error messaging
      enqueueSnackbar(error.response.data.message, { variant: "error" });

      // rethrow error for UI if it needs it
      throw error
    }
  }

  return { postWithoutAuth };
};
```

```js
import { usePostWithoutAuth } from '../hooks';

const Login = () => {
  const { postWithoutAuth } = usePostWithoutAuth();

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    postWithoutAuth(url, body)
      .then(data => ....)
      .catch(error => ....);
  };

  ...
};
```